# SwiftUI Views boards trembling after the app enters the foreground

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I noticed that for the view, the code of which is posted below, after the app went to the background and then enters the foreground again, the borders of the Rectangles trembling noticeably to an eye for maybe 0.3 seconds.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0...15, id: \.self) { _ in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(height: 50)
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this? Or what exactly cause this?

Comment: What borders? This just gives a solid blue screen with a tiny bit of white at the very top and very bottom.

Comment: This is the problem: if the application is goes the background and then the foreground borders between Rectangles appear for a split second

Comment: What are you testing on? I'm not seeing anything like you describe running the app in an iOS 17.2 iPhone 15 Pro simulator.

Comment: I tried different simulators and a real device. Perhaps the problem is in my Xcode, it's 15.0 I'll install the latest

Comment: I tried on Xcode 15.3 beta 2 and iPhone 15 (iOS 17.0) still can see trembling